# Class File : constructor

Tags: java, file

I have a simple question concerning the File class. In an example I saw:
    `File path = new File(".");`
I don't understand what "." means. To what directory does it refer?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`"."`, in the context of the file system, in almost all languages refers to the current working directory.

`new File(".");` means, "Give me a file object which is referencing the directory that this application is currently working in." This is generally, but not always, the directory the application was called from.

Answer (score 1):

The "." path generally refers to the current working directory. Admittedly, I'd argue that it might make sense to use the system property that gives you the same information, in case you happen to be running on a system where that isn't the case:

```
File path = new File(System.getProperty("user.dir"));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use "." to refer to the current directory of the filesystem or ".." to refer to the parent of the current directory.